# Inspect element in Firefox from within Emacs

Tags: web-browser

In Firefox, when I right-click anywhere on a web page and select "Inspect Element" from the popup menu, Firefox will open its Developer Tools and show me the properties for that element and other useful information.

What I'm hoping to find is an Emacs package that offers all of the functionality and information the Firefox Developer Tools offers, but within Emacs.

That information would still be coming from a given tab within a running Firefox instance, but the Firefox Developer Tools window would not even be opened.

NOTE:  This question is *not* a duplicate of ["inspect element" for GUI elements?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/66391/inspect-element-for-gui-elements).  The linked-to question might appear at first glance to be asking about how to inspect a Firefox element from within Emacs (which is what my question is about), but is actually about something different: how to inspect Emacs GUI elements.

Comment: I'm not sure, but this sort of thing could be more viable with chromium, as it has its own remote protocol for dev tools and debugging, which is used by the likes of node.js. I'm assuming it might be possible to use this protocol, and implement it in emacs, so it can "remotely" debug a web browser. I'm not sure whether firefox has such capabilities.